# How can we see users’ information through Facebook Graph API in Android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making a dating app (android) by using Facebook API (You know the similar application that starts with tin…)

Anyways, I registered my application in Facebook developers and I also got approval to use functions that I need through 'Submit Items for Approval'(my Approved Items: email, public_profile, User_photo, User_like, user_work_history, user_education_history )

So, I can log in from my app using my Facebook ID and I can also see users’ basic information too.

But! The main problem is that I cannot see photos (except public_profile) even though I was approved for this.

So I really need someone’s help. Please help me!

It will be great if you can review the code I used (To use when looking at users’ photos)

```
new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "/{user-id}/albums", null, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {

       @Override
       public void onCompleted(Response response) {                       }                                                  
        }).executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Use the following code. It works perfectly for me.

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
        accessToken,
        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(
                   JSONObject object,
                   GraphResponse response) {
                // Application code
            }
        });
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "photos.limit(100)");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

Try the above code and you will get a jsonobject which can be used to get the image URLs. To know the response you get. Try Graph API explorer. The response format will be the same. 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

if you would like to get the photos of a user try the following code. Please note that you need the user-id to they photos

```
new Request(
    session,
    "/{user-id}/photos",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

Please refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It enables call up my account information. However, it will not be able to get the account information of other people. Do not possible to obtain information on authorized people?

Comment: You can get the photos of another user only if you have their user-id. Use the following code above(I have redited)to get the photos of a user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use facebook graph api for accessing user info

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
    accessToken,
    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(
               JSONObject object,
               GraphResponse response) {
            // Application code
        }
    });
```

To call this method, use below line,

```
request.executeAsync();
```

For additional info visit facebook official documentation
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It enables call up my account information. However, it will not be able to get the account information of other people. Do not possible to obtain information on authorized people?